# Convert string into list of lists in python

Tags: python

```
    I have a string like below I would like to convert this string into list of lists:

issues = '[ [this is not a good book as i told ] ,
            [we are going to book shop to buy good books], 
            [I bought one good book for you] ]'
```

I have tried this below code getting an error:

```
import ast
result = ast.literal_eval(issues)
result

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-86-ef20f1c8417e>", line 2, in <module>
    result2 = ast.literal_eval(result2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
```

Expecting output like below as list of lists:

```
result = [ [this is not a good book as i told ], 
           [we are going to book shop to buy good books], 
           [I bought one good book for you] ]
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: aren't there any commas ?

Comment: @Rakesh please check now ... question modified

Comment: answer = [[x] for x in issues.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
issues = '[ [this is not a good book as i told ] ,[we are going to book shop to buy good books], [I bought one good book for you] ]'

a = [i for i in issues.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(',')]
l=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    f= []
    f.append(a[i])
    l.append(f)

print l
```

Comment: Thnaks for ur ans rahil... i'm expecting output should be list of lists not list of strings.

Comment: @van der Zon Stef oneliner in the comments is more efficient and neat.

Comment: if string is like this issues = '[ [this is not a good, book as i told ] ,
            [we are going to book, shop to buy good books], 
            [I bought one, good book for you] ]' is it possible to get desired output.

Comment: then you can try to split the string on `]`. Not sure though, for that, you have to try yourself, if after many tries you are not able to achieve, then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably expect output like this:

```
[['this is not a good book as i told'], 
['we are going to book shop to buy good books'], 
['I bought one good book for you']]
```

Below is the code:

```
import re

issues = '[ [this is not a good book as i told ]  [we are going to book shop to buy good books]  [I bought one good book for you] ]'

step_1=re.sub('\[ +\[','',issues)

step_2=re.sub('\] +\[',',',step_1)

step_3=re.sub('\] +\]','',step_2)

print([[i.strip()] for i in step_3.split(',')])
```